# Need to pull IP address and Serial Numbers from a list of hostnames

Tags: powershell

Trying to pull IP addresses and Serial Numbers from computers on the network using Powershell. I have a list of the hostnames, but I am absolutely useless at Powershell. I've figured out how to ping the computers to see what's up, but I need it to return the IP addresses and Serial Numbers as well. Searching the internet, I haven't really found what I'm looking for, but here's the script I've found for pinging machines:

```
$Output= @()
$names = Get-content "hnames.txt"
foreach ($name in $names){
  if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $name -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue){
   $Output+= "$name,up"
   Write-Host "$Name,up"
  }
  else{
    $Output+= "$name,down"
    Write-Host "$Name,down"
  }
}
$Output | Out-file "C:\PSPing\result.csv"
```

This works beautifully but it doesn't have the other things I need it to return and I have no idea what I'm doing :D

Comment: Q: Have you tried Google "Powershell serial number"?  For example: https://www.groovypost.com/howto/find-your-windows-10-pcs-serial-number-the-easy-way/  Just add `Get-WmiObject win32_bios | select Serialnumber` to what you've already got for "IP".

Comment: Oh wait where it said "Write-IP" was me adding things to the script.. I forgot to take that out. I fixed that with an edit.

Comment: Something like [this](https://community.spiceworks.com/scripts/show/4899-get-systeminfo)?